# ¿Por qué no se repite el segundo ciclo?

Tags: php

Presento un problema con la ejecucion de un ciclo anidado de while mediante un FETCH_ARRAY el cual nada mas se realiza de forma correcta en el primer ciclo pero no en el segundo quise graficalo de esta manera:

tabla uno.

```
numero {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

tabla dos.

```
letra {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}
```

este es el código:

```
<?php  
require 'conexion.php';

//Busqueda general de tecnicos
$sql_numero = "SELECT * FROM numero";
$resultado_numero = $mysqli->query($sql_numero);

//Busqueda general de servicios.
$sql_letra = "SELECT * FROM letra";
$resultado_letra = $mysqli->query($sql_letra);

while($row_numero= $resultado_numero->FETCH_ARRAY(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row_numero['numero']."<br>";

    while($row_letra= $resultado_letra->FETCH_ARRAY(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "  - ".$row_letra['letra']."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

resultado en pantalla.

```
1

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- f
- h
- i
- j
- k

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

Answer (score 2):

El error es simple, al culminar el segundo ciclo while, el puntero estará en el último registro del resultado de `$resultado_letra`.

Por lo cuál para la segunda iteración *(del primer ciclo)* ya no habrá filas por recorrer.

La solución para este caso es utilizar la función [mysqli_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) para ajustar el puntero de  la consulta al primer registro, es decir la **posición 0**.

```
while($row_numero= $resultado_numero->FETCH_ARRAY(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row_numero['numero']."<br>";
    while($row_letra = $resultado_letra->fetch_array())
    {
        echo "  - ".$row_letra['letra']."<br>";
    }

    mysqli_data_seek($resultado_letra,0); //aquí ajustamos el puntero.
}
```